# Database Connection Issues With Asp.NET 5 Web App on Mac

Tags: database-connection, yeoman, asp.net-core, npgsql, visual-studio-code

I am working with the visual studio code IDE for mac. I created an asp.net web application using yeoman. I am able to pull up the asp.net site using `dnx: kestral` from vscode. But when I click the "Register" or "Log In" menu I get

> SocketException: Could not resolve host '(localdb)'

From what I see, the config.json file has the standard localdb connection string, which expects a local SQL Server database. Not sure if this will work on mac.

I tried to change this to connect to a postgresql db I have running locally but I don't know how to configure the app to use npgsql. I added npgsql to my project.json and ran the `dnu restore`. I then tried a connection string like this

> Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=fooapp;User Id=user;Password=somepassword

But I receive this error

> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported : 'port'.

Does anyone know how to connect asp.net 5 to postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to install the .NET Data Provider for PostgreSQL and add it to your project references. Did you try that? If not, try the following from your command line:

```
dnu install Npgsql

dnu restore
```

Comment: I tried those dnu commands, but I still get the ArgumentException: Keyword not supported : 'port'. issue

Comment: I'mk not sure the current npgsql is an entity framework 7 compatible driver. Looks in the website if is good for asp.net 5 and the format of the connection string

Comment: I found that if you include a comma between the host and port, you're a step closer to where you want to be: Server=localhost,5432;blah... I include this as a comment since I'm still getting errors, but the db is canceling my connection, which I haven't figured out yet, but I at least know I'm talking to the thing now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Entity Framework 7 for now is not compatibile with any open RDBS (Well, maybe with SQLite). I was looking to run MySQL and Postgresql with asp vnext but without any effect..
Worse, I can't find any official information about the ETA for adding support into EF7 for those.